# How to pass JSON to webpage on load of page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a ASP.NET MVC 1.0 app.

I have a listbox on the page and I want to pass an array to the webpage so that
javascript can use the array to do some processing depending on the item picked 
in the listbox.

So I thought the best way is to pass JSON data to the webpage on load.

So what is the best practice on how to do this?

Can you please give me a brief step by step process.

How do pass the array as JSON and how do I access it by index?

Appreciate someone getting me started on this.

Malcolm

Comment: I am using JQuery also if that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller action:

```
public ActionResult Values(string someParameter) 
{
    return Json(new[]
    {
        new { Id = 1, Value = "value 1" },
        new { Id = 2, Value = "value 2" },
        new { Id = 3, Value = "value 3" },
    });
}
```

Javascript:

```
$.getJSON('<%= Url.Action("values") %>', { someParameter: 'some value' }, function(result) {
    $(result).each(function(index, item) {
        // TODO: Use item.Id and item.Value here
    });

    // or simply access the result variable by index ...
});
```